# Why does event.preventDefault() work without passing event as an argument in a callback function in some cases in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In almost all examples, "event" object is passed as an argument:

```
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

However, it seems that this also works in preventing the default behaviour of an anchor:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Can someone elaborate why the second one still works and what are the disadvantages?

Comment: Try it on Firefox, it will fail. :P

Comment: With out providing the argument, you cannot be sure that second one will work in all the places.

Comment: probably the some browsers are fixing your mistake...?

Comment: Because it is called by `anonymous function(event){}` which has jquery event as argument, so that event is accessible in your callback function

Comment: @itsgoingdown If that was universally true then it would work on FF as well.

Comment: @DaveNewton well downloaded FF now, and tried .caller of the callback function, and I am getting the `function(event){}` but `event` is not getting passed in FF. Don't know why http://jsbin.com/qejadu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: You are right. I tried it on Firefox and without putting event as an argument, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event.preventDefault()` works anyway. Implicitly `event` represents a DOM MouseEvent, if you send a `console.log(event)` without the event argument you'll check that, take a look:

```js
$('#my_button').on('click', function() {
  console.log(event);
  
  // 1. Press F12 or Ctrl + Shift + I and check the console
  // 2. Click the button after run it
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="my_button" value="my_button" />
```

When you call event without arguments you are calling the default alias of the object representation. You can take it by passing another alias like "e" or "evt" but when you call it "event" you doing the same thing then a call without it (because you will work with "event" anyway).

In my thought there's no disadvantages because it's just "modes of using".

Comment: This way you're sure the event you're calling is the same and relative to your callback triggered. No chance to call something wrong.

Comment: I followed the advice of some people in the comments, and not passing "event" as an argument seems to not work in Firefox. I guess the best practice is to always use the argument